# First line of the output of a command within a bash script overriding the exit status

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to execute a test bash script within a function in another shell script.
The function takes a parameter which is the test bash script (`echo` command), and would then check for the exit status. The problem here is the exit status is taken as the first line of the test script output.

SCRIPT : `single_run.sh`

```
    function sing_run() {
    exec_script=$1
    `$exec_script`
    return_status=$?

    if [[ `$return_status` = "0" ]]; then
    echo "SUCCESS"
    else
    echo "FAILURE"
    fi

    }

    sing_run "/bin/bash -x /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/scripts/test_run.sh | tee -a /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/logs/testing.log"
```

SCRIPT : `test_run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is a test script"
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
bash -x single_run.sh
+ sing_run '/bin/bash -x /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/scripts/test_run.sh | tee 
-a /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/logs/testing.log'
+ exec_script='/bin/bash -x /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/scripts/test_run.sh | 
tee -a /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/logs/testing.log'
++ /bin/bash -x /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/scripts/test_run.sh '|' tee -a 
/home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/logs/testing.log
+ echo 'This is a Test Script'
+ This is a Test Script
single_run.sh: line 5: This: command not found
+ return_status='echo 127'
++ echo 127
+ [[ 127 = \0 ]]
+ echo FAILURE
FAILURE
```

How can i get the correct exit status rather than `This` as the exit status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myfunc()
{
  bash -x $1 | tee -a output.log
}

myfunc $1

if [ $?=0 ] 
  then 
    echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failure"
fi
```

This will execute the script and check the return code

Comment: Worked outside func,but not inside:
        #!/bin/bash
        function sing_run() {
        `bash -x $1 | tee -a output.log`
        if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
        echo "SUCCESS"
        else
        echo "FAILURE"
        fi
        }
        sing_run '/home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/scripts/test_run.sh'

O:
+sing_run /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/scripts/test_run.sh
++bash -x /home/mspprod/customers/adobe/prod/scripts/test_run.sh
+echo 'This is a Test Script'
++tee -a output.log
+This is a Test Script
single_run.sh: line 4: This: command not found
+[[ 127 = 0 ]]
+echo FAILURE
FAILUR